# Hibernate thows java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm new to hibernate and I'm trying to write hibernate HQL programs using Eclipse IDE and when I try to use "HQL From" hibernate throws error saying that there is no CreateQuery() method. I tried importing org.hibernate.query.Query which also didn't seem to work.

I am getting the following error,

```
        Apr 04, 2018 12:01:26 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.11.Final}
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:26 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    Hibernate Configuration loaded
    Hibernate serviceRegistry created
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:28 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
    WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud]
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
    INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:28 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
    INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:28 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    Apr 04, 2018 12:01:29 PM org.hibernate.search.engine.Version <clinit>
    INFO: HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.8.0.Final
    Hibernate session factory created
    Beginning transaction.
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/Query;
        at com.crud.HQLExamples.main(HQLExamples.java:31)
```

The main class looks like this

```
    //------HQLExamples.java--------------

package com.crud;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.crud.Employee;
import com.crud.HibernateUtil;

public class HQLExamples 
{

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked"})
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        //Prep work
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        //HQL example - Get All Employees
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println("Beginning transaction.");

        Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee"); 
        List<Employee> empList = query.list();
        for(Employee emp : empList)
        {
            System.out.println("List of Employees::"+emp.getId()+","+emp.getAddress().getCity());
        }

        //HQL example - Get Employee with id
        query = session.createQuery("from Employee where id= :id");
        query.setLong("id", 3);
        Employee emp = (Employee) query.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("Employee Name="+emp.getName()+", City="+emp.getAddress().getCity());

        //HQL pagination example
        query = session.createQuery("from Employee");
        query.setFirstResult(0); //starts with 0
        query.setFetchSize(2);
        empList = query.list();
        for(Employee emp4 : empList)
        {
            System.out.println("Paginated Employees::"+emp4.getId()+","+emp4.getAddress().getCity());
        }

        //HQL Update Employee
        query = session.createQuery("update Employee set name= :name where id= :id");
        query.setParameter("name", "Pankaj Kumar");
        query.setLong("id", 1);
        int result = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Employee Update Status="+result);

        //HQL Delete Employee, we need to take care of foreign key constraints too
        query = session.createQuery("delete from Address where id= :id");
        query.setLong("id", 4);
        result = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Address Delete Status="+result);

        query = session.createQuery("delete from Employee where id= :id");
        query.setLong("id", 4);
        result = query.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Employee Delete Status="+result);

        //HQL Aggregate function examples
        query = session.createQuery("select sum(salary) from Employee");
        double sumSalary = (Double) query.uniqueResult();
        System.out.println("Sum of all Salaries= "+sumSalary);

        //HQL join examples
        query = session.createQuery("select e.name, a.city from Employee e "
                + "INNER JOIN e.address a");
        List<Object[]> list = query.list();
        for(Object[] arr : list)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }

        //HQL group by and like example
        query = session.createQuery("select e.name, sum(e.salary), count(e)"
                + " from Employee e where e.name like '%i%' group by e.name");
        List<Object[]> groupList = query.list();
        for(Object[] arr : groupList)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }

        //HQL order by example
        query = session.createQuery("from Employee e order by e.id desc");
        empList = query.list();
        for(Employee emp3 : empList)
        {
            System.out.println("ID Desc Order Employee::"+emp3.getId()+","+emp3.getAddress().getCity());
        }

        //rolling back to save the test data
        tx.rollback();

        //closing hibernate resources
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

}
```

pom.xml looks like this

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.crud</groupId>
  <artifactId>HQLExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks

Comment: Check if you have any duplicate jars in the build path, remove any old versions of the conflicting jars and try again. Also check if all hibernate jars are compatible with each other.

Comment: Changed "hibernate-core" version from 4.3.5 to 5.2.11 and it worked. But now I'm getting "com.hibernate.Query" deprecated warning. @BarathVutukuri

Comment: is it com.hibernate or org.hibernate? A deprecated warning tells that that particular method or class might be removed in future releases. But the code will work fine as of now.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Hibernate 5.2 and newer, You should use Query<> method (org.hibernate.query.Query package), then it will work flawlessly.